# Python random number list executing in vim

Tags: python, python-2.7, vim, random

I want to create a random number list in vim using a python command.

This works fine:

```
,!python -c "import random; print([random.uniform(1,10) for i in range(7)])"
```

but it overwrites the current line, it does not add every number on a new line and there is no way to format the output
I know I can use something like this `print '%04.3f' %` but it expands the `%` with current buffername.

How can I print to a new line, add every number to a new line and format the output values (in current buffer)?
This all from the vim command line (I don't want to use external python scripts).

ps:
I know that you create random numbers also in vim using `reltime()` and `reltimestr` but I noted that it is not random, random and python generates numbers much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:r!` command to insert the result of the command instead of replacing.

```
:r!python -c "import random; print('\n'.join(str(random.uniform(1,10)) for i in     range(7)))"
```

NB. Python code was slightly modified to print multiple lines.

- using generator expression and [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)
- I should converted float to str to use `str.join`.

---

To use [`str % ...`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting), you need to escape `%` using backslash:

```
:r!python -c "import random; print('\n'.join('\%04.3f' \% random.uniform(1,10) for i in range(7)))"
```

Alternatively, you can use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) or [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) instead of [`%` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting):

```
:r!python -c "import random; print('\n'.join('{:04.3f}'.format(random.uniform(1,10)) for i in range(7)))"
```

Comment: Thank you very much falsetru. Is random.uniform() a valuable random number picker? Another way is random.random() * 100 but it is the seem way of random number picking isn't it?

Comment: @Remonn, Sorry, I'm not good at random number generation algorithm. How about reading [the documentation for `random` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)?

Comment: I want to execute your command in a vimscript using variables for format and the range numbers, but I have troubles with the quotes. Can you please help me or do I have to create a new question? This must be the final form: `exe 'r!python -c "import random; print('\n'.join(' .value1.' \% random.uniform( .value2. ) for i in range( .value3. )))"'`

Comment: @Remonn, I'm not good at `exe` command neither. How about post another question?

Comment: Oeps... Locale.. Your command prints with dots (correct). I'm trying to switch it to my locale adding this `r!python -c "import random,locale; locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, ''); ` but where do I have to place `locale` in `:r!python -c "import random; print('\n'.join('\%04.3f' \% random.uniform(1,10) for i in range(7)))"` to format to my locale??

Comment: @Remonn, Use `locale.format('%04.3f', ...)` instead of `'%04.3f' % ...`.